# get value of href inside of div from external site using PHP

Tags: php, html

good day Sir/Maam.

I have a certain html attribute that I want to search from the external website

I want to get the a href value but the problem is the id or class or name is random.

```
<div class="static">
<a href="http://www.mysamplesite.com/" id="dynamicid" class="dynamicclass" name="dynamicname">Dynamic</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually what do you mean by "**I want to search from the external website**" ? Are you trying to set search url or trying to get data from specific url?

Comment: the value of href

Comment: So how do you know which one you want?

Comment: the href value but the a name/id/class are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

This code should display all the hrefs in http://example.com

In this case I use DOMDocument and XPath to select the elements you want to access because it's very flexible and easy to use.

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$nodeList = $xpath->query("//a/@href");

print_r($nodeList);

// To access the values inside nodes
foreach($nodeList as $node){
  echo "<p>" . $node->nodeValue . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: @MarverickM. Did you try this?

Answer (score -1):

use jquery to get the value as follow:

```
var link = $(".static>a").attr("href");
```

Comment: I am looking for PHP

Comment: use ajax to send the herf value to your php page.

Comment: I use ajax to load the .php page but I want to use PHP script to get the a href value

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP DOMDocument:

```
<?php
      $exampleurl = "http://YourDomain.com"; //set your url
      $filterClass = "dynamicclass";

      $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
      @$dom->loadHTMLFile($exampleurl);
      $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

      foreach ($anchors as $element) {
          $href = $element->getAttribute('href'); // all href
          $class = $element->getAttribute('class');
          if($class==$filterClass){
            echo $href;
          }
      }
?>
```